# jQuery DIV click() taking over DIV.IMG click()

Tags: jquery, click

i tried using stopPropagation() without luck.
I've this structure:

```
<div class="logos">  
</div>
```

I've a click binded to logos, that appends img elements inside it ends up like:

```
<div class="logos">
  <img width="100" height="80" src="/js/fileupload/uploads/Penguins.jpg">  
  <img width="100" height="80" src="/js/fileupload/uploads/Hydrangeas.jpg">
</div>
```

I want to bind a click event to those image, so when they're clicked they can be removed from the "logos" div, i used .live() to track those clicks.
The result is that when i click an image, both the "logos" click event and the img click event are fired.

```
    $('.logos img').live('click', function(e){
        var answer = confirm ("Delete image?")
        if (answer){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $('.logos').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.qq-upload-button input').trigger('click'); //File uploader that uploads images and creates the img elements.
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried placing e.stopPropagation(); in the img function?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on both functions, and with e.stopPropagation() and e.stopImmediatePropagation()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this. If you are using > jQuery 1.4 you should be using `on` instead of `live`. Check the target and if it is an image then remove it. Otherwise leave it be.

http://jsfiddle.net/AprTx/

```
$('.logos').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($(e.target).is('img')) {
        $(e.target).remove();
    }
    else {
        $(this).append($('<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />'));
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

That was from the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/on/), but also place your `e.stopPropagation()` on your images before the click propagates to the parent! :)

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/esazok/3/edit)**

```
$('.logos img').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var answer = confirm("Delete image?");
        if (answer){
            $(this).remove();
        }
});

$('.logos').click(function(){
     $('.qq-upload-button input').click();
});
```

Comment: @doterobcn Edited my answer, I missed a small detail. If I understand you well, if someone deletes an image you want to upload (call) a new one ?

Comment: @roXon no, when you click on an image, it has to be removed, then if they click again on the parent div, they can add another one

Comment: @roXon thanks for your time, it still doesn't work with my jQuery version, mrtsherman code works perfect, but thanks anyway i appreciate the effort!! :)

Comment: @doterobcn youre welcome! tought you're gonna update your jQuery v. :) bye